# How to load an image from ASP.NET MVC controller in a Facebook canvas app?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, facebook-c#-sdk

In my Facebook canvas application, I want to load an image from my ASP.NET MVC Controller.
So I do somethinhg like this, in my controller (simplified):

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
  // ....
  return File(@"c:\temp\1.jpg", "image/jpeg");
}
```

And it's called from my aspx page like so:

```
<img src="/Home/GetImage?id=20" alt="Test"/>
```

But the image is not displayed, I get a "red x".

So I fire up Fiddler and see that the request does indeed return the image, but the data is prepadded with Facebook's frame html:

`<html><head><script type="text/javascript">
top.location = "http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?state=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://localhost:5000/facebookredirect.axd";
</script></head><body></body></html>?????JFIF??H?H????
?ICC_PROFILE???
????????mntrRGB XYZ ?????$?acsp???????????????????????????????????`

Which of course is not vaild jpeg image data.

How can I avoid this pre padded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found out myself that the signed_request data was (yet again) missing.

I thought the only way to pass this was thru a HTTP header, but (like magic) I could pass it as a parameter as well causing the request to be validated.

```
<img src="/Home/GetImage?id=20&signed_request=<%=Request.Params["signed_request"] %>" />

public ActionResult GetImage(int id), string signed_request)
{ 
  var auth = new CanvasAuthorizer(); 
  if (auth.Authorize()) 
  { 
    // Indeed, I'm now authorized 
    return File(@"c:\temp\1.jpg", "image/jpeg");
  }
   /// ... 
}
```

/M